# Slot replication not working in Postgres 9.4

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-replication

I am using Postgres 9.4 on Windows 2008 server. There are three such instances that I am using. One as master and the rest of the two are slave/standby. The version of Postgres is 9.4 in all the three instances. I have set up replication using physical slot. But the replication is not working. On querying `SELECT * from pg_stat_replication`; 0 rows are returned and on `SELECT * from pg_replication_slots`; the slot shows it is not active ('f' in the 'active' column).

I have the following configuration :

On Primary/Master:

1. wal_level = hot_standby
2. max_wal_senders = 2
3. max_replication_slots = 2
4. hot_standby = on

On Secondary/Standby:

1. wal_level = hot_standby
2. hot_standby = on

recovery.conf file on secondary/standby:

1. standby_mode = on
2. primary_conninfo = 'host=192.168.8.192 port=5432
   user=postgres password=123456'
3. primary_slot_name = 'testing'
4. recovery_min_apply_delay = 1min

What could be missing? I have bootstrapped Standby servers with Master's data backup. Thanks.

Comment: When I create slot by query "SELECT * FROM pg_create_physical_replication_slot('testing');", the slot created is inactive. Why would this query create an inactive slot?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Ubuntu. For me in turned out that `replication.conf` was not in the right location.

According to the Postgres Wiki on [Streaming Replication](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication) in the section that describes recovery.conf:

> $EDITOR recovery.conf
>
> Note that recovery.conf must be in $PGDATA directory.
>
> It should NOT be located in the same directory as postgresql.conf

Once I moved `recovery.conf` to the right location and restarted Postgres, `SELECT * from pg_stat_replication` returned `active = true`.

Hope that helps.